# Select start time between start and end time

Tags: t-sql

I want to fetch the start time but it should not be in between start and end time (fetching with the reference of another table). I ve tried up but am getting error. Can anyone help me on this.?

```
SELECT DISTINCT right(start_time,7) AS st_time
FROM Session_Info
WHERE CourseName = 'Java'
  AND (right(start_time,7) NOT IN BETWEEN
         (SELECT right(start_time,7)
          FROM Session_Info
          WHERE Session_Id IN
              (SELECT Session_Id
               FROM sessions
               WHERE UserId='a')) AND
         (SELECT right(end_time,7)
          FROM Session_Info
          WHERE Session_Id IN
              (SELECT Session_Id
               FROM sessions
               WHERE UserId='a')))
```

Also am reusing the same query like (select Session_Id from sessions where UserId='a') how to store it in a variable?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Also, couple comments - "in between" is not valid syntax; and generally, you should use `join` statements rather than `in` statements, your query performance will suffer greatly otherwise.

Comment: getting incorrect syntax near between

Comment: The `BETWEEN` keyword is for when you're comparing a single (scalar) value against two other single values. You've got incorrect use of keywords mixed with incorrect use of sub-queries that will most likely return a list/set of information instead of a single value. Perhaps you could clearly state what data you want and people can write some SQL that works? Also tell us what database you're using.

Comment: sql server. i want to get start time from session_info table. the scenario is like suppose i ve enrolled for java course at 07:00AM to 09:00AM means and again whem am trying for new enrollment i should not able to select same timing and inbetween the enrolled timing

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code to something like

```
SELECT  DISTINCT right(start_time,7) AS st_time
FROM    Session_Info
WHERE   CourseName = 'Java'
        AND Session_ID IN (SELECT Session_ID FROM sessions WHERE UserId = 'a')
        AND NOT (right(start_time,7) BETWEEN right(start_time,7) AND right(end_time,7))
```

OR using CTE

```
;WITH mySessionIDs (Session_ID)
(
    SELECT  Session_ID
    FROM    sessions
    WHERE   UserId = 'a'
)
SELECT  DISTINCT right(si.start_time,7) AS st_time
FROM    Session_Info si
        INNER JOIN mySessionIDs
            ON si.Session_ID = mySessionIDs.Session_ID
WHERE   si.CourseName = 'Java'
        AND NOT (right(start_time,7) BETWEEN right(start_time,7) AND right(end_time,7))
```