# keep javascript dropdown selections from $(window).on('load', function()

Tags: javascript, html

i am using a slightly modified version of a script from here,[Select start time between start and end time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594129/select-start-time-between-start-and-end-time)

the script

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

$("select[name='SelectedTime1']").on("change", function(){
    $("select[name='SelectedTime2']").empty();
    var startix = $("select[name='SelectedTime1'] option:selected").index();
    $("select[name='SelectedTime1'] option").each(function(ix, el){
        if (ix >= startix) {
            $(this).clone().appendTo("select[name='SelectedTime2']");
        }
    });
});

    });
```

script to keep the selected times in each dropdown after the page reloads.

```
  function show2(time1) { 
  var success = -1;
  for (var i=0; i < document.frmLocate.SelectedTime1.length; i++) {
    if (document.frmLocate.SelectedTime1.options[i].value == time) 
      success = [i];
  }
  document.frmLocate.SelectedTime1.selectedIndex=success;
}
function show4(time2) { 
  var success = -1;
  for (var i=0; i < document.frmLocate.SelectedTime2.length; i++) {
    if (document.frmLocate.SelectedTime2.options[i].value == time) 
      success = [i];
  }
  document.frmLocate.SelectedTime2.selectedIndex=success;
```

the dropdowns

```
<label for="SelectedTime1-set">1st Time:
  <select name="SelectedTime1" id="SelectedTime1-set">
    <option>08:00 AM </option>
    <option>09:00 AM</option>
    <option>10:00 AM</option>
    <option>11:00 AM</option>
    <option>12:00 PM</option>
    <option>01:00 PM</option>
    <option>02:00 PM</option>
    <option>03:00 PM</option>
    <option>04:00 PM</option>
    <option>05:00 PM</option>
    <option>06:00 PM</option>
    <option>07:00 PM</option>
    <option>08:00 PM</option>
    <option>09:00 PM</option>
  </select></label>
  &nbsp;
      <label for="SelectedTime2-set">2nd Time:
      <select name="SelectedTime2" id="SelectedTime2-set">
        <option>08:00 AM </option>
        <option>09:00 AM</option>
        <option>10:00 AM</option>
        <option>11:00 AM</option>
        <option>12:00 PM</option>
        <option>01:00 PM</option>
        <option>02:00 PM</option>
        <option>03:00 PM</option>
        <option>04:00 PM</option>
        <option>05:00 PM</option>
        <option>06:00 PM</option>
        <option>07:00 PM</option>
        <option>08:00 PM</option>
    <option>09:00 PM</option>
  </select></label>
  &nbsp;
```

these two dropdowns are part of a form that submits back to the page after it executes an API request and SelectedTime2 should not be before SelectedTime1

both dropdowns have the same options 8AM through 9PM. the script will hide the times in SelectedTime2 which are before the time selected in SelectedTime1.

what i need to have happen: after the form is posted, have the earlier times in SelectedTime2 remain hidden.

the selected times remain after post but the earlier times in SelectedTime2 unhide.

i am hoping to prevent future tech support calls for "Why is the page blank" because they dont pay attention to AM/PM. they select 6PM first and 9AM 2nd when it should be 9PM.

Thanks

Sean

Comment: Why don't you call your dropdown menus `Start time` and `End time` to avoid confusion? Also you could just check if the second value entered is greater than the first one and return an error if so.

Comment: I could change names but I dont find it confusing. As far as the error... that would generate calls as well. Better to not give the option.

Comment: You could check for errors using javascript and prevent sending a post request.

Comment: i was able to figure it out, merged 2 scripts into a function that fires with the first dropdown choice also on page load. i am going to clean up the naming convention and repost when i am finished just incase it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

did some housekeeping and merged 2 into 1 function

the dropdowns

```
   <label for="StartTime-set">1st Time:
      <select name="StartTime" id="StartTime-set" onchange="setEndDate()">
        <option>08:00 AM </option>
        <option>09:00 AM</option>
        <option>10:00 AM</option>
        <option>11:00 AM</option>
        <option>12:00 PM</option>
        <option>01:00 PM</option>
        <option>02:00 PM</option>
        <option>03:00 PM</option>
        <option>04:00 PM</option>
        <option>05:00 PM</option>
        <option>06:00 PM</option>
        <option>07:00 PM</option>
        <option>08:00 PM</option>
        <option>09:00 PM</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    &nbsp;
    <label for="EndTime-set">2nd Time:
      <select name="EndTime" id="EndTime-set">
        <option>08:00 AM </option>
        <option>09:00 AM</option>
        <option>10:00 AM</option>
        <option>11:00 AM</option>
        <option>12:00 PM</option>
        <option>01:00 PM</option>
        <option>02:00 PM</option>
        <option>03:00 PM</option>
        <option>04:00 PM</option>
        <option>05:00 PM</option>
        <option>06:00 PM</option>
        <option>07:00 PM</option>
        <option>08:00 PM</option>
        <option>09:00 PM</option>
      </select>
    </label>
```

the function

```
function setEndDate() { 

    $("select[name='EndTime']").empty();
    var startix = $("select[name='StartTime'] option:selected").index();
    $("select[name='StartTime'] option").each(function(ix, el){
        if (ix >= startix) {
            $(this).clone().appendTo("select[name='EndTime']");
        }

}); 
  var success = -1;
  for (var i=0; i < document.frmLocate.EndTime.length; i++) {
    if (document.frmLocate.EndTime.options[i].value == endTime) 
      success = [i];
  }
  document.frmLocate.EndTime.selectedIndex=success;

}
```

the body tag

```
<body onload="setEndDate()">
```

when the page loads or the StartTime dropdown is changed the EndTime dropdown is set. an initial choice must be made for EndTime when the page is first loaded which is more desireable in my case.

hopefully someone will find it useful or suggest some additional cleanup.